# condition to excecute button onClick not running as expected?

Tags: android, if-statement, onclick

I want to "enter" `lay2` **only** if the phonenumber(`phone`) hasn't been filled in yet, otherwise it should never leave `lay1`.

I thought I could do this with a simple `if/else` condition, but it doesn't work. And, more surprising, the `Toast` I added doesn't display either which is highly odd to me since its supposed to run if the `if` condition is `false`. (So either I would get taken to `lay2` or the `Toast` would display but neither happens)

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ph0ne.getText().toString()==null){
                lay1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TEST CHAT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        lay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `.show()` on your `Toast` so of course it doesn't show.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TEST CHAT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

All you are actually doing inside the `else` is creating the `Toast` but never displaying it. If you used logs or breakpoints, I'm sure you would see it entering the `else`.

Not sure but you may also want to check if the phone number actually has text and not just if it's `null` or not. By checking that it doesn't equal `""` after checking if it's `null` or checking the length.